# making strsql from sql with different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So i need to make a strsql like this one :

```
strSQL = "SELECT "
strSQL = strSQL & " tblclips.fldclipid, "
strSQL = strSQL & " tblPlatenfirma.fldplatenfirmaID, "
strSQL = strSQL & " tblClips.fldUitvoerder, "
strSQL = strSQL & " tblClips.fldTitel, "
strSQL = strSQL & " tblPlatenfirma.fldnaam"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM "
strSQL = strSQL & " tblClips "
strSQL = strSQL & " INNER JOIN tblPlatenfirma "
strSQL = strSQL & " ON tblClips.fldplatenfirmaid = tblPlatenfirma.fldplatenfirmaID"
strWHERE = ""
```

But i got a SQL code that I don't understand so with the result I can't make a strSQL, I really need this for a school project and i got a few days left. This is the SQL i don't understand:

SELECT tbluurroosterleerkracht.flduurroosterleerkrachtID AS uurroosterID,         tblklas.fldnaam AS Klas, tbllokaal.fldnummer AS Hoofdlokaal, tblvak.fldvak AS Vak,  tbllokaal_1.fldnaam AS LesLokaal, tbllokaal_2.fldbeschikbaar AS beschikbaar, tblleerkracht.fldnaam AS NaamLeerkrachtNormaal, tblleerkracht.fldvoornaam AS  VoornaamLeerkrachtnormaal, tbldag.flddag AS Dag, tbllesuur.fldvan AS Van, tbllesuur.fldtot   AS Tot
FROM (((tbllokaal AS tbllokaal_2 RIGHT JOIN (tblvervangingen LEFT JOIN tblleerkracht AS   tblleerkracht_1 ON tblvervangingen.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht_1.fldleerkrachtID) ON   tbllokaal_2.fldlokaalID = tblvervangingen.fldlokaalID) LEFT JOIN tbltaak ON  tblvervangingen.fldtaakID = tbltaak.fldtaakID) LEFT JOIN tblleerkracht AS tblleerkracht_2  ON tbltaak.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht_2.fldleerkrachtID) RIGHT JOIN (((tbllokaal AS tbllokaal_1 INNER JOIN (((tbldag INNER JOIN (tblklas INNER JOIN tbluurroosterleerkracht ON tblklas.fldklasID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldklasID) ON tbldag.flddagID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.flddagID) INNER JOIN tblvak ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldvakID = tblvak.fldvakID) INNER JOIN tbllokaal ON tblklas.fldlokaalID = tbllokaal.fldlokaalID) ON tbllokaal_1.fldlokaalID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldlokaalID) INNER JOIN tbllesuur ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldlesuurID = tbllesuur.fldlesuurID) INNER JOIN tblleerkracht ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht.fldleerkrachtID) ON tblvervangingen.flduurroosterleerkrachtID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.flduurroosterleerkrachtID
ORDER BY tblleerkracht.fldnaam, tblleerkracht.fldvoornaam, tbldag.flddag,   tbllesuur.fldvan;

Answer (score 0):

It is an unusual SQL query. Are you sure it produces the result you want?

When trying to understand code it is useful to format it so that you can clearly see each part of it. This is particularly true for big SQL queries, and code with lots of nested bracketted bits.

Here is the SQL with my rough formatting applied...

```
SELECT 
  tbluurroosterleerkracht.flduurroosterleerkrachtID AS uurroosterID,
  tblklas.fldnaam AS Klas,
  tbllokaal.fldnummer AS Hoofdlokaal,
  tblvak.fldvak AS Vak,
  tbllokaal_1.fldnaam AS LesLokaal,
  tbllokaal_2.fldbeschikbaar AS beschikbaar,
  tblleerkracht.fldnaam AS NaamLeerkrachtNormaal,
  tblleerkracht.fldvoornaam AS VoornaamLeerkrachtnormaal,
  tbldag.flddag AS Dag,
  tbllesuur.fldvan AS Van,
  tbllesuur.fldtot AS Tot 
FROM
 (
   (
    (tbllokaal AS tbllokaal_2 
     RIGHT JOIN (tblvervangingen 
                LEFT JOIN tblleerkracht AS tblleerkracht_1 
                ON tblvervangingen.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht_1.fldleerkrachtID
                ) 
     ON tbllokaal_2.fldlokaalID = tblvervangingen.fldlokaalID
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN tbltaak 
    ON tblvervangingen.fldtaakID = tbltaak.fldtaakID
   )
   LEFT JOIN tblleerkracht AS tblleerkracht_2
   ON tbltaak.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht_2.fldleerkrachtID
 ) 
 RIGHT JOIN 
 (
   (
     (tbllokaal AS tbllokaal_1 
      INNER JOIN 
       (
         (
           (tbldag 
            INNER JOIN 
             (tblklas 
              INNER JOIN tbluurroosterleerkracht 
              ON tblklas.fldklasID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldklasID
             ) 
            ON tbldag.flddagID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.flddagID
           ) 
           INNER JOIN tblvak 
           ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldvakID = tblvak.fldvakID
         )
         INNER JOIN tbllokaal 
         ON tblklas.fldlokaalID = tbllokaal.fldlokaalID
       ) 
       ON tbllokaal_1.fldlokaalID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldlokaalID
     ) 
     INNER JOIN tbllesuur 
     ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldlesuurID = tbllesuur.fldlesuurID
   ) 
   INNER JOIN tblleerkracht 
   ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht.fldleerkrachtID
 ) 
 ON tblvervangingen.flduurroosterleerkrachtID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.flduurroosterleerkrachtID 
ORDER BY 
  tblleerkracht.fldnaam, 
  tblleerkracht.fldvoornaam,
  tbldag.flddag,
  tbllesuur.fldvan;
```

Is there a specific part that you do not understand?

I think despite not understanding how the SQL works. Your string building method should still work as a way to store the sql in a program variable.

Comment: I need to put this in a strsql for visual basic but the sql code uses '(' and because of that I don't understand it.

Comment: Do you know which DB the SQL is intended to run on? Brackets '(',')' in the FROM clause in most DBs will cause a syntax error to be returned.